# Problem with building Packer image from JSON

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

Good day!
i try to build packer image from JSON to AWS but I have a strange problem:
Build 'amazon-ebs' errored: error validating regions: RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post https://ec2.us-east-1a.amazonaws.com/: dial tcp: lookup ec2.us-east-1a.amazonaws.com: no such host

Answer (score 1):

You are using an invalid region, replace `us-east-1a` with `us-east-1`.

`us-east-1a` is the name of an *availability zone* (AZ). Those doesn't have an API endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

**linux**:

run `export AWS_REGION=us-east-1` on your console
*OR* 
Edit /etc/environment with `export AWS_REGION="us-east-1"`

**Windows**:

run `set AWS_REGION=us-east-1` on your console
*OR*
edit C:\Users\USERNAME.aws\config with `[default]
region = your_aws_region`